# Why deepcopy doesnt create new references to lambda function?

Tags: python

Found this strange in python:

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = [SomeClass()]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Output:

```
>>> a
[<__main__.Some instance at 0x10051b1b8>]
>>> b
[<__main__.Some instance at 0x10051b092>]
```

This is just as expected- deepcopy created new `SomeClass()` object for b.

But if,

```
f = lambda x:x+1
a = [f]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

I get:

```
>>> a
[<function <lambda> at 0x10056e410>]
>>> b
[<function <lambda> at 0x10056e410>]
```

Why deepcopy doesnt create a new lambda instance in the second case? does that mean lambda functions are atomic?

Comment: I don't think lambdas are mutable, so there shouldn't be any reason to make copies...

Comment: Thats what I currently assume..

Comment: @Radu Function objects are mutable. Try `func.my_outlandish_attr = func`, no matter if `func` is named or anoynmous. Or even more feindishly, `func.co_code = other_func.co_code` (`__code__` in Python 3; does not work with builtins) which actually changes the code of the function!

Comment: paging Alex Martelli, please share thoughts on this ..

Answer (score 6):

This applies not just to lambdas, but to functions without state more generally.

```
>>> def some_function(word): print word
>>> a = [some_function]
>>> a
[<function some_function at 0x1007026e0>]
>>> copy.deepcopy(a)
[<function some_function at 0x1007026e0>]
```

Because the functions do not store state, deepcopy does not create a new reference for them. An interesting discussion of topics similar to this issue (though not exactly the same issue) is recorded here: http://bugs.python.org/issue1515

Comment: Again, functions (including lambdas; those even have the same type!) *are* mutable. See the answer by Noctis Skytower.

Comment: Edited accordingly :) Thanks.

Comment: They do have state. Even immutable objects have state, but beside that, some attributes such as `__code__` and `__doc__` are also writable. What do you mean by "do not store state"?

Comment: OK, I guess more specificity is in order. How do you feel about store *instance* state, or state we would care about changing within the general use-case of deepcopy, as opposed to a singleton or global state that is more rarely changed from call-to-call of a given function.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to say. Even what a call to the function does and which arguments it accepts depends on mutable state of the function object.

Comment: Mutable perhaps, but not (by convention) mutated. From Guido vR in the thread linked above, "A (bound) method contains an instance which definitely represents state and calling the method can easily mutate that state. This is different from classes (which could contain state) or modules (which almost certainly contain state) or functions (which could mutate global state) -- in all those cases, we're talking about singleton state, for which it makes sense not to create a clone."

Comment: "Not mutated by convention" makes sense, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

As a side note to some people thinking that lambdas are not mutable, observe the following behavior:

```
>>> a = lambda x: x + 1
>>> a(12)
13
>>> b = lambda x: x - 1
>>> b(12)
11
>>> a.__code__ = b.__code__
>>> a(12)
11
>>>
```

Comment: +1 Though it's no answer. Thank you for pointing it out, with a great example too. Note that it's `co_code` in Python 2 and only works for user-defined functions. Even more aside, you can engineer your own code objects, without writing out a function - you may even crash the interpreter that way if you construct invalid code.

Comment: Sorry, typo: It's `func_code` in Python 2. `co_code` is an attribute of the code object which stores the raw bytes which form the bytecode, and keeps that name in Python 3.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question !!

Comment: @YugalJindle: This may not answer the question, but it should clear up confusion caused by other answers. **delnan** references this answer twice to correct some misleading statements.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at lines [222 and 223 from the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.3/Lib/copy.py#l222):

```
d[types.BuiltinFunctionType] = _deepcopy_atomic
d[types.FunctionType] = _deepcopy_atomic
```

The module considers them atomic, and I don't know how you can mutate a lambda.

Comment: Again, functions (including lambdas; those even have the same type!) *are* mutable. See the answer by Noctis Skytower.

Comment: it is quite common to modify function attributes in a decorator e.g., `functools.wraps()` (`__name__`, `__doc__`, etc attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the complete history of Python, but it's possible that functions used to be as immutable as strings and tuples, and so that originally it was perfectly reasonable for `deepcopy` to behave as it does.

Also, in practice, most people are more concerned that their data objects are being copied than their functions. The necessity for `deepcopy` to make a copy of functions is a clear edge case, and expecting people subject to that edge case to roll their own solution seems perfectly fine to me.

A reasonable approach would be to write a decorator `@copyablefunc` that wraps the function in a callable object (i.e. a class that has a `__call__()` method) and that also defines `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()` methods to be used by the `deepcopy` routine.

`copy.deepcopy` also doesn't truly copy classes, just by the way.